# Best approach to keep both iOS6 and iOS7 support?

Tags: ios, ios6, storyboard, ios7

As you know, soon we will have the new iOS7 release, and then we are supposed to adapt our App's to the new flat style.

My question is: does anybody know which is the best practice to have a temporary coexistence of the iOS 6 (skeuomorphic) and the iOS 7 (flat) design?

The best for me would be the possibility of 2 different Storyboards per device-screen-size, and "preprocesor directives" for retrieve the iOS version...

What do you think?

NOTE: I know that if you adapt your app to iOS7 (and you configure it properly), you can run it on iOS6, the problem is that the changes that you will do to adapt to iOS7, would make your app look ugly in iOS6...

Comment: This depends entirely on what you app is doing, how much custom UI there is, etc.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking in the most general case: app with native elements and some small customization of controls and UI...

Answer (score 4):

We updating our app from Old Type graphics in iOS6.1 to a new style Flat ever in iOS6.1 when the iOS7 Stable is ready we can update the core with functionality but the graphics style is so new see my screen:

Before on iOS6:

[image]

**After a WWDC on iOS7 we make an update with this style:**

[image]

**The correct question is what you want to do after the iOS7 is Ready? if you want to update your app only for iOS7 or create an update retroactive from iOS6.1 to iOS7 is only your strategy.**

Hope my think is good :)

Comment: That's a pretty good approach.

Comment: My question is, what would be the aspect of your app in iOS6 after releasing the iOS7-adapted-version... It won't look as it was before...

Comment: Actually we starting test on iOS7beta2 and Xcode beta2 on iPhone5, the old core of this app have no problem to running very well, it is obvious in the iOS7 there other UI to implement, but is very powerfull retroactive ;)

Comment: There is no reason why you can't support both iOS 6 and 7 and keep the old look when run under iOS 6 and a new look when run under iOS 7 or later. It is each developer's choice if the iOS 6 look should change or not. Personally, I think iOS 6 users are not going to like all of their apps changing looks just because iOS 7 came out.

Comment: @rmaddy this is true and you have the reason, but the problem is old look not working very well, because is different in more part, but if you continue to develop iOS7 retroactive on iOS6 you have a lot of time to change your look step by step, remember all of us there we have to fight with Jaibreaker and lazy people, they have no reason to updating on iOS7 and is probable they says iOS7 is not good is like Android look :S

Comment: @Jhon Keep in mind that iOS 7 will not run on all devices that can run iOS 6. So it's not just lazy people that will stay on iOS 6.

Comment: @rmaddy sure I had not thought :) we have to fight with the last iPod 3gen and iPhone3Gs :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that one approach is to rely heavily on

- Auto Layout (to deal with different sizes of controls and text)
- UIAppearance (to change backgrounds and tints depending on style in a single place depending on the OS version)

Then just check for the availability of new features like UI[REDACTED] and [REDACTED]Kit before using them in your app. (iOS 7 is still under NDA).