# Remove border navigation bar buttons monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

So I'm creating an interface with images on the buttons but by default apple puts borders arround the navigation bar buttons. Is there an easy way to remove them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your interface builder select a button and on propertis on right column make it `Custom` button with background image:

[image]

[image]

after adding a normal UIButton you have a Interface Builder Alert (can be use plain button) simple, one click on a button and set it Bordered custom:

[image]

After other click on the same button and setting with first screen ;)

Comment: This is not possible with UIBarButtons.

Comment: with your screen you dont use a normal UIBarButton, but a normal UIButton and dragged in in to a nav bar, so if this is not true you can use a normal UIButton in to a navbar and settings like my post never add more code ;) i can add a screen on post to show the result and can setting a text attribute like a normal UIButton

Comment: Oh ok, I didnt know that you can add a normal uibutton to the navigation bar! Ill try this for sure.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal thx, i add a probable issue can appear on a interface builder

Comment: i see it look like a new iOS7 but on a iOS6 right? ;) same method for us take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17450237/best-approach-to-keep-both-ios6-and-ios7-support/17450598#17450598

Comment: Yea im changing the UI to get ready for IOS7. This way the app will look almost the same on IOS6 & IOS7 ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Add custom button to navigation controller without border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621160/add-custom-button-to-navigation-controller-without-border), you could

```
var button = new UIButton (new RectangleF (0, 0, 25, 25));
button.SetImage (new UIImage ("image"), UIControlState.Normal);

NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (button);
```

of course, if you want some control over your BarButtonItem, you can do this:

```
var button = new UIButton (new RectangleF (0, 0, 25, 25));
button.SetImage (new UIImage ("image"), UIControlState.Normal);

var buttonItem = new UIBarButtonItem (button);
buttonItem.SetTitleTextAttributes(...);
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

Comment: ok, This works but how would i use SetTitleTextAttributes on this?

Comment: keep a variable pointing to the UIBarButtonItem you create from the Button, on which you can call SetTitleTextAttribute

Comment: Hhm i get this error :  Argument `#1' cannot convert `System.Drawing.RectangleF' expression to type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIBarButtonSystemItem' (CS1503)

Comment: I completed the response, that should address your issue.